# Is it possible to have $A=A\times A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a non-empty set. We define $A\times A=\{(a,b):a\in A\wedge b\in A\}$ in which $(a,b):=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. My question is: is it possible to have $A=A\times A$?

I know that if $A$ is finite then $A\neq A\times A$. But is this also true in the case where $A$ is infinite?

I tried to prove that $A\neq A\times A$ using the axiom of foundation to get an absurd, but unfortunately I did not succeed.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense unless you fix a set theoretic definition of (a, b), using say the Kuratowski pair.

Comment: @user571438 I already edited my question.

Comment: Sorry, must have missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $A=A\times B$, and that $A$ is nonempty.

Then the set
$$ C = A\cup\{\{x\}\mid x\in A\} $$
would be a counterexample to the axiom of regularity.

No element of $A$ is disjoint from $C$ -- because each element is an ordered pair that contains the singleton of its first element, which is itself in $A$. And clearly no $\{x\}$ with $x\in A$ is disjoint from $C$ either.

In other words, the axiom of regularity says that *there is no (nonempty) set $X$ such that every element of $X$ has an element that is also in $X$ itself*. Such a set would (with a minimal amount of choice) allow us to extract an infinitely descending $\in$-chain. But $C$ defined above would be a set of that form.

---

This reasoning depends on ordered pairs following the Kuratowski definition.  There are alternatives; for example, with [Quine-Rosser ordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Quine%E2%80%93Rosser_definition), the set $V_\omega$ of all hereditarily finite sets satisfies $V_\omega=V_\omega\times V_\omega$.